# Manipular página com WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, navegador-de-internet

Estou tendo problemas ao enviar valores para um formulário via `Web Browser`. Meu objetivo é fazer uma postagem, ou seja, enviar os valores para os `inputs`do formulário e fazer o `submit` do mesmo, após isso abrir a página gerada em meu navegador.

**Formulário:**

```
<form action="..." method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" name="postmodify" id="postmodify" class="flow_hidden" onsubmit="submitonce(this);smc_saveEntities('postmodify', ['subject', 'message', 'guestname', 'evtitle', 'question'], 'options');" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="subject" tabindex="1" size="80" maxlength="80" class="input_text" />


    <select name="icon" id="icon" onchange="showimage()">
        <option value="xx" selected="selected">Padrão</option>
        <option value="thumbup">OK</option>
        <option value="thumbdown">Negativo</option>
        <option value="exclamation">Ponto de exclamação</option>
        <option value="question">Ponto de interrogação</option>
        <option value="lamp">Lâmpada</option>
        <option value="smiley">Sorridente</option>
        <option value="angry">Zangado</option>
        <option value="cheesy">Contente</option>
        <option value="grin">Sorriso forçado</option>
        <option value="sad">Triste</option>
        <option value="wink">Piscar</option>
    </select>

    <textarea class="resizeble" name="message" id="message" rows="12" cols="600" onselect="storeCaret(this);" onclick="storeCaret(this);" onkeyup="storeCaret(this);" onchange="storeCaret(this);" tabindex="2" style="height: 175px; width: 100%; "></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" tabindex="3" onclick="return submitThisOnce(this);" accesskey="s" class="button_submit" />

</form>
```

**C#:**

```
WebBrowser oWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
oWebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
oWebBrowser.Navigate("meulink");

//botão para fazer postagem
private void postar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HtmlElement subject = oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")["subject"];
        if(subject != null)
        {  //tentativa de setar o subject
            subject.SetAttribute("value", assunto);
            MessageBox.Show("assunto");
        }

        HtmlElement ico = oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("icon");
        if (ico != null)
        { //tentativa de setar o icon
            ico.SetAttribute("value", m.traduzIcon(icon.Text));
            MessageBox.Show("icon");
        }


        HtmlElement message = oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("message");
        if (message != null)
        { //tentativa de setar o message
            message.InnerText = padrao;
            MessageBox.Show("padrao");
        }


        HtmlElement form = oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("postmodify");
        if (form != null)
        { //tentativa de dar submit
            form.InvokeMember("submit");
            MessageBox.Show("submit");
        }
        //tentativa de abrir o link da postagem
        ProcessStartInfo post = new ProcessStartInfo(oWebBrowser.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        Process.Start(post);

    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERRO");
    }
}
```

Ao executar ele não exibe nenhum `MessageBox` e abre meu navegador na página definida no `Web Browser` (`meulink` - a que tem o formulário). Alguém pode me dar um help? Não sei como fazer isso direito, estou me baseando em pesquisas.

Comment: esse endereço `meulink` é uma página qualquer, tipo `www.google.com.br` ou é uma página da sua aplicação? Ela poderá ser acessada sem ser pelo seu sistema?

Comment: É uma página normal de um fórum formada por `php`, pode ser acessada sem meu sistema. Seria uma tela de login e outra uma tela de postagem de um fórum e esse sistema será apenas para agilizar as postagens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [`WebBrowser.Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) carrega a página de maneira assíncrona, para você manipular o documento deve esperar que o documento tenha sido carregado.

Você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras:

1. Programando o evento `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` ([Solução citada neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925022/webbrowser-document-is-always-null))
2. Colocar o código abaixo para garantir que o código não avance até que a página tenha sido carregada (Isto deve ser feito após o método `Navigate` e após a chamada `form.InvokeMember("submit");`) ([Solução citada neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583897/c-sharp-how-to-wait-for-a-webpage-to-finish-loading-before-continuing)):

`while (oWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
      Application.DoEvents();
    }`

Fiz um exemplo funcionando com o código abaixo (Ele carrega a página do Stackoverflow e faz uma busca por uma palavra chave). Criei uma simples aplicação Windows com um formulário, um componente WebBrowser(Que nomei oWebBrowser igual a você) e um botão. Todo o código executa no click do botão, que está abaixo:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Resposta a pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109853/manipular-p%C3%A1gina-com-webbrowser
            oWebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            oWebBrowser.Navigate("https://stackoverflow.com/");

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583897/c-sharp-how-to-wait-for-a-webpage-to-finish-loading-before-continuing
            while (oWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925022/webbrowser-document-is-always-null
            MessageBox.Show(oWebBrowser.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri);

            HtmlElement questionInput = oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("q");
            if (questionInput != null)
            {
                questionInput.SetAttribute("value", "WebBrowser");
                MessageBox.Show("encontrou o campo valor");
            }

            HtmlElement questionForm = oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("search");
            if (questionInput != null)
            {
                questionForm.InvokeMember("submit");
                MessageBox.Show("Fez submit");
            }
            while (oWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }    
            MessageBox.Show(oWebBrowser.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri);

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299273/how-do-i-submit-a-form-inside-a-webbrowser-control
        }
```

---

**Edit1:**

Acredito que você deva estar com problema em selecionar o controle corretamente. Apliquei a mesma ideia de solução acima, na página de login que citou e realmente tive que tomar alguns cuidados para achar os controles e definir os valores.

Dicas para você: Se eu buscasse um elemento com o nome "User", não retornava o input do login. Nesse caso então busquei primeiro o formulário pelo Id `oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("frmLogin")`. Depois eu busquei o controle de nome user dentro do formulário achado `form.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("user")[0]`. A mesma ideia foi feita para a senha.

Aplicando o código abaixo, é feita a tentativa de login, mas obviamente, não tenho um usuário e senha válido. Veja, por favor, se consegue solucionar com essas dicas.

```
            oWebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            oWebBrowser.Navigate("gsmfans.org/index.php?action=login");

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583897/c-sharp-how-to-wait-for-a-webpage-to-finish-loading-before-continuing
            while (oWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete &&
                oWebBrowser.Document == null)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925022/webbrowser-document-is-always-null
            MessageBox.Show(oWebBrowser.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri);

            HtmlElement form = oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("frmLogin");

            HtmlElement userInput = form.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("user")[0];
            if (userInput != null)
            {  //tentativa de setar o subject
                userInput.SetAttribute("value", "TesteUser");
                userInput.ScrollIntoView(true);
                MessageBox.Show("user");
            }

            HtmlElement passwordInput = form.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("passwrd")[0];
            if (passwordInput != null)
            { //tentativa de setar o message
                passwordInput.SetAttribute("value", "TestePass");
                MessageBox.Show("password");
            }

            if (form != null)
            { //tentativa de setar o message
                form.InvokeMember("submit");
                MessageBox.Show("submit");
            }

            while (oWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete &&
                oWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
```

Comment: Testei copiando e colando seu código e deu certo, adaptei ao fórum e ao inputs e não consegui, inicialmente seria com essa página para fazer o login: http://www.gsmfans.org/index.php?action=login e com essa para postar: http://www.gsmfans.org/index.php?action=post;board=1304.0;  não é exibido nenhum erro, nem `MessageBox` na tela (até quando coloquei `else` no not null)

Comment: Fiz o Edit1 aplicando um código que localiza e tenta fazer o login na página que citou. Tive que buscar o controle com mais critério, conforme explicado. Além disso, a página que citou nunca chegava ao estado de completa `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`, também fiz ajuste para isso.
Veja se resolve o seu problema

Comment: Valeu, funcionou perfeitamente estava cometendo um equivoco ao tentar pegar o elemento pelo nome, nas pesquisas estava assim como na pergunta rs..  A recompensa só posso ativar daqui 2 horas. Valeu ai mano

Comment: Beleza! Quando puder, passa a recompensa pois estou começando agora a ajudar a turma por aqui e vou vai me dar mais opções de interagir.